# Binder Service as a Separate Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, aidl

I have created a service to run in a separate process

```
<service
    android:name="dashboard.main.InterfaceService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":ServiceProcess" >
</service>
```

I have read than when service is made as separate process it is on a separate thread not on main thread. When I do HTTP Request in service I get exception: `Thread forbids Http`.

Thread info of both main thread and service thread are same main:`(id)1:(priority)5:(group)main`.

service is `started/bind()` in `MainActivity`.
Interaction between is using AIDL.

After service connected MainActivity Holds reference of an object returned by service and i use this object for further making calls for methods of service.

In DDMS view two separate processes are visible

please help, i need to make service run on its own thread

------------ new info
as "acj" suggested - i did PID check in all classes. 
Since both process have different heap the object that returned from my service through AIDL was made another copy in activities heap. So every time i used this object to initiate Http Request, i was using the object present in Activity Process Heap i.e. its on main thread.

Is my Inference proper?

Comment: are you using StrictMode? I ask because why it is forbidden is weird to me. Usually you can do whatever you want but it will pop up an ANR if you are blocking the process' main Looper. It should not prevent you from using http

Comment: It looks like AndroidHttpClient checks whether it's running on the main Looper before allowing the request to proceed ([source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java#L99)), so it ends up preempting StrictMode and NetworkOnMainThreadException and creating confusion.

Comment: Ahhh, yikes, I have not used that class yet. Well that sucks. Yeah each process has a main looper. I would just not use the AndroidHttpClient. Use the HttpUrlConnection directly. I suspect this is running on 2.3 or higher. So HttpUrlConnection should be safe to use, and then the whole issue goes away

Comment: @harshal No, it shouldn't matter which copy of the object you're using. Android will route any method calls into the other process on your behalf. To state the problem simply: you're blocking the UI thread by calling into your service through the object. This is ok for fast operations (milliseconds), but not for slow ones.

Comment: the object which i returned has methods that make HTTP requests and i used service to create them, this should make it clear. My mistake was i needed to receive communication and make HTTP calls in service Process itself rather than returning object to main thread.

Answer (score 3):

Don't look for thread info, rather print out process and/or thread ID to confirm if the service and the application are running in separate threads/processes.

```
android.os.Process.myPid()/android.os.Process.myTid()
```

My best guess is that each individual process in Android has a main thread by default and that's probably because you see the same information. Also, if that is true, then main thread never allows to make any network calls which is application for a process running service as well and you must use some AsyncTask or create a new thread for that. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's one way to think both process (Service as process and activity) has main thread. Need to research on it...

Comment: In DDMS view two seperate processes are visible, with ID 852(Activity) and 851(Service). but i try to find PID in code both process returned 852 Activities. what did i miss?

Comment: Things look fine in your manifest file. Where are you trying to print PIDs from? Also, can you please copy your complete <service> tag from your manifest file?

Comment: Also, can you please try changing android:process=":serviceprocess". It shouldn't make any difference, but it works for me.

Comment: Capitalizing (or not) the first letter of the process name is mentioned in the [Service documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html):  "If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage."  This may lead to security issues, so please be careful.

Comment: i did read on that capitalizing but did not use because of security caution

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Was just wondering why you not getting different PIDs and if it makes any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

From the [AIDL docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html):

> By default, **RPC calls are synchronous**. If you know that the service takes more than a few milliseconds to complete a request, you should not call it from the activity's main thread, because it might hang the application (Android might display an "Application is Not Responding" dialog)—you should usually call them from a separate thread in the client.

When you call a method on your `IBinder` instance to do the HTTP request, the calling thread (in this case, probably the UI thread) is blocking and triggering the exception. To take advantage of the service's background thread, you should send work to it through an `Intent`.

Depending on your requirements, an `IntentService` or an `AsyncTask` may be a better approach.

If you use an `IntentService` (even in the same app process), the `Intent` will be handled on a background thread. You will need a mechanism for sending results back to the client (your `Activity` in this case); I've used a `BroadcastReceiver` for this purpose.

If your service only makes short HTTP requests and returns the results to an `Activity`, then an `AsyncTask` will be much simpler to implement.

**EDIT**:

I think there is some confusion about how Android handles threads. The problem with your architecture is that you're calling a long-running method on an `IBinder` object, and you're calling it from the UI thread of your app. This type of RPC call **will block** while the method runs and will cause the exception that you're describing.

The recommended way to send long-running work to a service is through an `Intent`. As I said earlier, an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) will handle its intents in a background thread automatically and doesn't need a separate process. (A separate process is generally needed only if the service is likely to crash and you don't want it to bring down the app.)

Comment: any info on why service in separate process thread's info and activity main thread's info are same.

Comment: intention of going for separate process for service was that it would be in different thread and i don't have to bother about stalling main thread

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's difficult to say why the thread info would be the same. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I read if service is in separate process that means separate thread from UI then for rest of my code in UI i just request for service and no need to create thread for each http request. But some thing is missing... thanks for input's

Comment: Using a separate process does create a new "main" thread, but please understand: calling into the service through the `IBinder` object that it returns *does not* use that new thread. To avoid the "thread forbids HTTP" exception, your service needs to be an `IntentService` and you need to queue long-running work using Intents. ... Your work will be much easier if you use an `AsyncTask` and avoid the service entirely. If you must use a service, an `IntentService` will manage the thread problem for you. No separate process, no AIDL, no worrying about threads. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

bindService() creates a binderThread in the service's process(creates a new MainThread) which is of "main" group. So technically the methods inside the AIDL stub interface are being run on a different process but on the main thread. To solve this problem you can either use IntentService which will start a worker thread, but if you must return the value from the AIDL methods then you can use a HnadlerThread inside a your service with a callback for completion. below is the example

**MyAIDLInterface.aidl**

```
import com.example.todokotlin.ResultCallback;
interface IMyAidlInterface {
    void add(int a, int b,ResultCallback callback);
}
```

**ResultCallback.aidl**

```
interface ResultCallback {
    void onResult(int result);
}
```

**MyService.kt**

```
class MyService: Service() {

    lateinit var handlerThread:HandlerThread

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        handlerThread = HandlerThread("MyService",Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)
        handlerThread.start()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return object:IMyAidlInterface.Stub(){
            override fun add(a: Int, b: Int,callback: ResultCallback){
                Handler(handlerThread.looper).post{
                    Thread.sleep(60000) // you can do you HTTP call hear
                    callback.onResult(a+b)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
            handlerThread.looper.quitSafely()
        else
            handlerThread.looper.quit()
        return super.onUnbind(intent)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
            handlerThread.looper.quitSafely()
        else
            handlerThread.looper.quit()
    }
}
```

for calling the remote interface pass the ResultCallback from the client after setting up the usual serviceConnection and bindingService

**ClientActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mService: IMyAidlInterface? = null

    private val mConn:ServiceConnection = object: ServiceConnection{
        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
            mService = null
        }

        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
            mService = IMyAidlInterface.Stub.asInterface(service)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        startButton.setOnClickListener {
           mService?.add(5,5,object : ResultCallback.Stub() {
              override fun onResult(result: Int) {
                 runOnUiThread {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                 }
              } 
           })
        }
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val i = Intent()
        i.component = ComponentName(packageName,packageName+"MyService")
        bindService(i,mConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        unbindService(mConn)
    }

}
```

Above approach also helps you queuing multiple client request.